# On the integral $ \int \cos(x)^{{\cos(x)}}\mathrm{d}x$.

Tags: definite-integrals

I would like to know if there is a closed formula for the integral 
$$
\int \cos(x)^{{\cos(x)}}\mathrm{d}x\overset{? }{=}
$$
in terms of $\pm x^{\pm n}$, $(\pm\cos(x))^{\pm 1}$, $(\pm\sin(x))^{\pm 1}$, $ e^{\pm x}$, $ e^{\pm\cos(x)}$,$ e^{\pm\sin(x)}$  and Gamma function $\Gamma(x)$. For exemple
$$
\int \cos(x)^{{\cos(x)}}\mathrm{d}x\overset{? }{=}{e^x\cdot \cos(x)}+{\Gamma(x)\cdot e^{2x}}
$$
By *'closed formula'* I mean if there is a polynomial in several variables 
$$
p(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_r)=\sum_{i_1}\sum_{i_2}\ldots\sum_{i_r}a_{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_r}x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}\cdot\cdots\cdot x_r^{i_r} 
$$
such that
$$
\int \cos(x)^{{\cos(x)}}\mathrm{d}x=p(\varphi_1(x),\varphi_2(x),\ldots,\varphi_r(x))+C
$$
for $\varphi_1(x),\varphi_1(x),\ldots \varphi_r(x)\in \{\pm x^{\pm n}, (\pm\cos(x))^{\pm 1}, (\pm\sin(x))^{\pm 1}, e^{\pm x}, e^{\pm\cos(x)}, e^{\pm\sin(x)},\Gamma(x)^{\pm 1}\}$.

My attempt 
$$
  \int \cos(x)^{{\cos(x)}}\mathrm{d}x
= \int \exp\circ(\cos(x)\log({{\cos(x)}}))\mathrm{d}x
= \int \exp\circ(y\log({{y}}))\sqrt{1-y}\mathrm{d}y
$$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB%28cosx%29%5E%28cosx%29dx wolfram doesn’t think so

Comment: What is the motivation behind this, as it is there is no computation shown in the post.

Comment: Just by looking at it, you can tell that there is probably no closed form for the indefinite integral.

Comment: You may find an answer here (not exactly a duplicate) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral